# Python if statements-hackerrank

Tags: python, if-statement

Here is the question from challenges:

If  is odd, print Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
If  is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
If  is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

My code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())

if (n%2==1):  #print Weird for odd number
    print("Weird")
 
else if(n%2==0 for n in range(6,21)):  #to print Weird as output for numbers between 6 to 20 
    print("Weird")

else if(n%2==0 for n in range(2,6)):   #to print No weird for even number between 2 to 5
    print("Not Weird")
  
else if(n>20 and n%2==0):  #to print Not Weird for even greater than 20 
    print("Not Weird")
```

I am getting the wrong output for 24. Instead of showing Not Weird, I am getting Weird as output. Can you guide me where I went wrong?

Comment: HackerRank does have a forum section. So, you will get a better answer if you ask this question there itself.

Comment: Check `(n%2==0 for n in range(6,21)`. Not the right way to condition for your case.

Comment: i checked by replacing 'for' with 'and;..but need to undertand why it is failing with for here..i am trying to check the condition with for and  range @Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

you have taken the iterator variable as 'n' in for loop and the input is also 'n' that is confusing and wrong
and most importantly why are you running a loop to check whether a number is between a range or not?

try this

```
N = int(input())
if(N%2!=0):
    print("Weird")
elif(N%2==0):
    if(N>=2 and N<=5):
        print("Not Weird")
    if(N>=6 and N<=20):
        print("Weird")
    if(N>20):
        print("Not Weird")
```